# Returning siblings (child.parent.children) in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a better way to return the "siblings" of the children in a one-to-many relationship in Rails?  Assume standard associations have been set up.

For instance, now I would do something like:

`child.parent.children`

Or, to exclude the current record,

`child.parent.children - [child]`

This feels a bit dirty (Demeter violation?)... is there a more acceptable best practice?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no out-of-the-box way to do this.

Not going to be radical about it, but this is more acceptable, *in the sense that it **won't transform** your output*:

```
child.parent.children.where.not(id:child.id)
```

One other way to make it available to your objects, in Model (child.rb) definition:

```
def siblings
    parent.children.where.not(id:self.id)
end
```

and then you will have:

```
child.siblings
```

exactly as above

Comment: In newer Rails versions this can be achieved with `excluding`, like this: `parent.children.excluding(self)`